# How to get manual trigger button for a jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have a downstream jenkins job(B) which now gets triggered automatically by upstream job(A) if it is stable. But I want a manual trigger button in the pipeline view for job B. If job A is stable job B should wait for manual trigger to start. I'm using jenkins freestyle project for creating jobs.

Comment: Welcome So, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Already that is not a good question. At least you should show what have you done.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the downstream jobs from A. Follow the steps and disable first.

```
#goto the job B
#configure
#goto build triggers and uncheck the button
```

> build after other projects are built

So afterwards Job B will not get start automatically.  And now you can goto your pipeline view and see and edit.

Comment: But then Job B is then removed from the Build Pipeline view because it isn't associated in the stream anymore. Or am I misunderstanding?